# Looking for a way to excute a command line from cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to create a file and copy it somewhere by some code from cypress .

the first step is done by using cy.writeFile and now myfile.txt is created

Now i need to copy it somewhere like `c:/lib/Sth`

i used this command `cy.exec('cp myfile.txt c:/lib/sth')`

it shows this error message :

***CypressError: `cy.exec('cp myfile.txt c:/lib/sth') failed because the command exited with a non-zero code. Pass` {failOnNonZeroExit: false}` to ignore exit code failures.
Information about the failure:
Code: 127***

I add `{failOnNonZeroExit: false}` to my code to ignore error , it works , but my file is not copied.

is there any other solution to copy my file from cypress ??

Comment: How are you adding the `{failOnNonZeroExit: false}` to your `cy.exec()` command?

Comment: can you copy it manually by executing `cp myfile.txt c:/lib/sth` from command line?

Comment: adding it like this cy.exec('cp myfile.txt c:/lib/sth',{failOnNonZeroExit: false});

Comment: absolutely , it works from the command line

Comment: myfile.txt position is relative to the cypress folder maybe you need to supply absolute path instead of relative

Comment: the same thing , it's not working

Answer (score 2):

A work-around you could do is set up a custom [cypress task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Usage) to execute a command.

Something like

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.ts
const { exec } = require('child_process');

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  on('task', {
    async execute(command: string) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          resolve(exec(command));
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    },
  });
};
```

Then execute like so

```js
cy.task('execute', 'cp myfile.txt c:/lib/sth');
```

This was a potential solution I came up with when `cy.exec()` didn't work for me either when trying to execute a relatively complex node script.

Another thing you could try is to create a really simple script that copies the file, and try executing that script.

Best of luck!